# How to Yield in a recursive function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a dictionary:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}}}
```

I need to create a dictionary as follows:

```
{'c':'d', 'e','f'}
```

It can go deeper up to any level but I should always get the key value pair at the maximum depth. So I wrote a function:

```
def boil_down_array(key, data):
    if type(data) == dict:
        for key, item in data.items():
            boil_down_array(key, item)
    else:
        yield {key:data}
```

Now the problem is, once it goes in recursion, the `yield` is lost. How do I yield that dictionary again? All I get is a generator which is not what I want.

Comment: But that returns a generator object instead of a dictionary

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) with your recursive call, otherwise you are just ignoring the result of the recursive call:

```
def boil_down_array(key, data):
    if type(data) == dict:
        for key, item in data.items():
            yield from boil_down_array(key, item)
    else:
        yield {key: data}
```

This is only available in Python > 3.3, but essentially just a short hand for simply yielding from an extra loop:

```
for key, item in data.items():
    for x in boil_down_array(key, item):  # just exhaust the recursive generator
        yield x  # and "re-yield" what it produces
```

In order to achieve your desired data structure, you might be better off yielding pairs instead of `dicts`, so you can transform the result more easily to the resulting `dict`:

```
yield key, data
```

Then you can use it like:

```
result = dict(boil_down_array(None, input_dict))
```

An even simpler recursive approach will just return a complete `dict`:

```
def boil_down_nested(dct):
    result = {}
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result.update(boil_down_nested(v))
        else:
            result[k] = v
    return result
```

Answer (score 11):

You are ignoring the generator object that the recursive call produces:

```
for key, item in data.items():
    boil_down_array(key, item)  # creates a generator object
```

so the recursive call is not actually executed (the code in your generator is never executed for that call).

You want to use `yield from` to [delegate iteration](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) to that call:

```
for key, item in data.items():
    yield from boil_down_array(key, item)
```

`yield from` moves control from the current generator to the iterator that the expression after `yield from` produces; here that's your recursive generator.

`yield from` requires Python 3.3 or newer. If you are using Python 2 or an older Python 3 release, you can also add another loop to explicitly yield each result produced by iteration:

```
for key, item in data.items():
    for result in boil_down_array(key, item):
        yield result
```

I'd also use `isinstance(data, dict)` rather than use `type(...) ==`, to allow for subclasses:

```
def boil_down_array(key, data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, item in data.items():
            yield from boil_down_array(key, item)
    else:
        yield {key: data}
```

Note that your code doesn't actually produce a dictionary as output. It produces an *iterable* of single key-value dictionaries:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}}}
>>> list(boil_down_array('v', d))
[{'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f'}]
```

The `key` argument from the outermost call is redundant here too, as you replace it with the key of the current iteration.

If you do need to stick with a generator function, then at least produce `(key, value)` tuples and don't bother with recursing when the *value* is not a dictionary (so test before you recurse), to remove the need to pass along the key; the remaining `data` argument is now assumed to be a dictionary, always:

```
def boil_down_nested(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from boil_down_nested(value)
        else:
            yield (key, value)
```

and use `dict(boil_down_nested(input_dict))` to produce a new dictionary from the key-value tuples the generator now outputs:

```
>>> next(boil_down_nested(d))  # first resulting key-value pair
('c', 'd')
>>> dict(boil_down_nested(d))  # all key-value pairs into a dictionary.
{'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

*Without* recursion, you can use a stack to track nested dictionaries still to process; this makes it much easier to just output a dictionary as a result directly:

```
def boil_down_nested_dict(d):
    stack = [d]
    output = {}
    while stack:
        for key, value in stack.pop().items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                stack.append(value)  # process this value next
            else:
                output[key] = value
    return output
```

No separate `dict()` call required anymore:

```
>>> boil_down_nested_dict(d)
{'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that you do not necessarily need to use `yield`:

```
def last(d):
  c = [i for b in d.items() for i in ([b] if not isinstance(b[-1], dict) else last(b[-1]))]
  return c

print(dict(last({'a': {'b': {'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}}})))
```

Output:

```
{'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```