# Generating Power Set with Recursion and Yield Statement in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, powerset

I am a bit new to Python and am working through programming exercises. I have written the following recursive method to generate the [power set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) based on an input list in Python. It should return a generator that generates the power set of a given list passed in as `s`. Each element in the power set should be a set.

```
def gps(s, res=set()):
    if s:
        elem = s.pop()
        gps(s, res)
        res.add(elem)
        gps(s, res)
    else:
        yield res
```

When I call it using `list(gps([1,2]))` however it gives me `[]`. The correct result should be something like `[set(), {1}, {2}, {1, 2}]`.

I removed the `yield` statement, added two lines of code and played around with `print` statements to get this code, which prints the right results and seems like a step closer:

```
def gps(s, res=set()):
    if s:
        elem = s.pop()
        gps(s, res)
        res.add(elem)
        gps(s, res)
        s.append(elem)
        res.remove(elem)
    else:
        print(res)
```

After reading another [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725568/how-to-yield-in-a-recursive-function-in-python/52725662) I modified my function to use `yield from` but the modified code below still gives me incorrect results:

```
def gps(s, res=set()):
    if s:
        elem = s.pop()
        yield from gps(s, res)
        res.add(elem)
        yield from gps(s, res)
        s.append(elem)
        res.remove(elem)
    else:
        yield res
```

Where am I going wrong with my approach? Any tips and clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the method need to be recursive?

Comment: It doesn’t, but my first thought was to write a recursive solution that has two recursive subcalls: one which generates all subsets that include a particular element and one which generates all subsets without that particular element.

Comment: Does the output order important/matter?

Comment: @james348943 Your idea of a recursive approach is correct. See my answer for a reference implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try this code, without any built-in methods.

```
def subset(nums):
    ans = [[]]

    for n in nums:
        ans += [a+[n] for a in ans]

    return ans


nums = [1, 2, 3]

print(subset([1,2,3]))  # [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Or you still prefer the **generator** version:

```
def powerset(nums):
    """
    This is a generator version
    """
    if len(nums) <= 1:
        yield nums
        yield []
    else:
        for x in powerset(nums[1:]):
            yield [nums[0]]+ x
            yield x



if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [1, 2, 3]
    print(list(powerset(nums)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) can be used to to get all combinations of elements in the list of a certain length. To get the powerset you can combine all combinations of length `0` with all of length `1` and so on up to the length of the list

```
import itertools

s = [1, 2]
result = []

for x in range(len(s) + 1): 
    result.extend(map(set, itertools.combinations(s, r=x)))

print(result)  # [set(), {1}, {2}, {1, 2}]
```

The original input should really be a set or at least have unique values, if the list has duplicates this may not work as the input was not a "set"

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive approach, as the title of the question suggests, you can make the function take out the first item of the input sequence and then recursively yield each subset from the powerset of the rest of the sequence, with and without the first item added:

```
def powerset(seq):
    if seq:
        first, *rest = seq
        for subset in powerset(rest):
            yield subset
            yield {first, *subset}
    else:
        yield set()
```

so that `list(powerset([1, 2]))` returns:

```
[set(), {1}, {2}, {1, 2}]
```

and that `list(powerset([1, 2, 3]))` returns:

```
[set(), {1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Since the time complexity of unpacking in `first, *rest = seq` in the above code (or slicing, in the case of `nums[1:]` in @DanielHao's answer) is *O(n)*, you can improve the time complexity of the step to *O(1)* by creating an iterator from the input sequence first so that you can fetch the next item from the sequence in constant time at each recursion level:

```
def powerset(seq):
    def _powerset(seq):
        try:
            first = next(seq)
            for subset in _powerset(seq):
                yield subset
                yield {first, *subset}
        except StopIteration:
            yield set()

    yield from _powerset(iter(seq))
```