# python combinations from lists

Tags: python, nested, generator, combinations

I have n generators in a list, each arbitrary length but none of them is empty.

```
lst = [gen_1, gen_2, ... gen_n]
```

I'd like to create the list A using the generators so that each element of A

- contains zero or one element from each generator
- all generators are exhausted when finsihing the creation of A

The content of A should be something like this:

```
gen_1[0]
.
.
gen_1[n]
gen_1[0], gen_2[0]
.
.
gen_1[n], gen_2[0]
.
.
gen_1[n], gen_2[m], ... gen_n[o]
```

In essence this is like creating the powerset using `itertools.combinations` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035595/powersets-in-python-using-itertools)), but we take zero to one element from each generator.

I imagine this would be solvable using recursion but can't wrap my head around it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are they generator *functions* or generator *iterators*?

Comment: generator functions. What difference would this make?

Comment: Functions let you iterate multiple times (so you don't have to store the elements elsewhere).

Comment: I see. All generators in the questions are generator functions yielding an iterable.

Comment: Why do you choose this way `generator` to make `powerset`?  Just to learn or other User cases?

Comment: @DanielHao it is a use case. Normally when iterating multiple iterables parallel e.g. with zip the iteration stops after the shortest iterable is exhausted.

Comment: @DanielHao more importantly the generators provide elements by certain rules (all of the elements, only one of them, all combinations etc) so using a simple powerset was not possible

Comment: @jake77 I see.  What I saw it is the close similarity with this `powerset` post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124242   <---- just change to `generator list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the empty combination and then one by one consider each further generator and the combinations it contributes:

```
def gen_1():
    yield from 'ab'
def gen_2():
    yield from 'XY'
def gen_3():
    yield from [1, 2]
lst = [gen_1, gen_2, gen_3]

A = [[]]
for gen in lst:
    A += [a + [g]
          for a in A
          for g in gen()]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(A)
```

You could also swap the order of the list comprehension's two `for` clauses. Would likely be more efficient. I've done it the above way partly in order to somewhat use that they're generator functions and support multiple iterations.

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCsMgEETv@xV7i5JQSHIphR78ixaRYommQqJiveTrrUZKoWQuAzNvZ/0WX86OZx9SmpTGWdlHT@gFMGszaplQB7diI58NfIHhCLjdf8B4APC@w0HA8o54Rb7/6epatVEAsFJxIUC7UEI0FvNB3WLY5lZim6/FnlQVVhaS/YVzCfMKoXnarN6FiN4HYyNUO1UjjKb0AQ)):

```
[[],
 ['a'],
 ['b'],
 ['X'],
 ['Y'],
 ['a', 'X'],
 ['a', 'Y'],
 ['b', 'X'],
 ['b', 'Y'],
 [1],
 [2],
 ['a', 1],
 ['a', 2],
 ['b', 1],
 ['b', 2],
 ['X', 1],
 ['X', 2],
 ['Y', 1],
 ['Y', 2],
 ['a', 'X', 1],
 ['a', 'X', 2],
 ['a', 'Y', 1],
 ['a', 'Y', 2],
 ['b', 'X', 1],
 ['b', 'X', 2],
 ['b', 'Y', 1],
 ['b', 'Y', 2]]
```